# Airflow task is not stopped when execution timeout gets triggered

Tags: airflow

I have my own custom operator extends BaseOperator as follows.
I tried to kill a task if the task runs for more than 30 minutes. 
timeout seems to be triggered according to a log but the task still continued.

Am I missing something? I checked the official document but do not know what is wrong.
https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#baseoperator

My operator is like as follows.

```
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
      self,
      some_parameters_here,
      *args,
      **kwargs):
      *args,
      **kwargs):
      super(MyOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      # some initialization here

    def execute(self, context):
      # some code here
```

My task is like as follows.

```
t = MyOperator(
     task_id='task',
     dag=scheduled_dag,
     execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30)
```

I found this error but the task continued.

```
[2018-04-12 03:30:28,353] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [Stage 6:==================================================(1380 + -160) / 1224][2018-04- 
12 03:30:28,353] {timeout.py:36} ERROR - Process timed out
```

Ref.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This airflow job runs Spark job.
So, I need to stop Spark session when on_kill method is called on timeout.

```
def on_kill(self):
    if (self.spark):
        logging.error('on_kill: stopping spark session...')
        self.spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your task code contains 'except Exception' like this.

```
def func(**kwargs):
    try:
        time.sleep(3*60)
        _log.info('sleep 3*60s finished')
    except Exception:
        _log.error('except exception:', exc_info=True)
    return 'success'
```

It will catch the AirflowTaskTimeout Exception, so that process won't abort as expected.

```
[2019-12-27 10:59:54,064] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-12-27 10:59:54,061] {timeout.py:42} ERROR - Process timed out, PID: 62104
[2019-12-27 10:59:54,065] {test_timeout.py:61} ERROR - except exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/airflow/dags/test_timeout.py", line 58, in func
    time.sleep(3*60)
  File "~/airflow/airflow/utils/timeout.py", line 43, in handle_timeout
    raise AirflowTaskTimeout(self.error_message)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: Timeout, PID: 62104
[2019-12-27 10:59:54,070] {python_operator.py:115} INFO - Done. Returned value was: success
```

Use specified Exception type may solve this question.